# Automatic/Scheduled JavaScript on Website

Tags: javascript, automation, macros, scheduled-tasks

On my University there's a website for booking project rooms; but unless you're lucky or awake at midnight, it isn't easy to actually get a room. So I wrote a JS snippet that fills out all the necessary fields and submits the form.

**But how do I automate this process?**

My intent is basically to load up the website and run a JS snippet on that website on a scheduled basis, preferably without the use of external automation/macro software.

Comment: So what exactly is supposed to run the snippet if not external automation software...?

Comment: @ChrisG well, I was thinking of some VBScript or command line stuff coupled with Windows Task Scheduler.

Comment: Just google your question title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could easily get it done using [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer), basically something like

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
setInterval(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://example.com');
    await page.evaluate(() => {
        // your snippet
    });
    await browser.close();

}, 1 * 60 * 60 * 1000); // every 1 hour
```

Comment: Yeah, I actually just stumbled upon puppeteer, will give it a go!

Quick question: My snippet uses a MutationObserver to advance in the function, will that work with puppeteer?

Comment: @Androvich yes, it would work, basically when you evaluate code, its the same as you run code in the browser console, and puppeteer internally just uses a chromium browser, please look at the link for the api, its very rich.

Comment: @Androvich and if you are gonna use Windows Task Scheduler, you could avoid the `setInterval` and let the task scheduler do it, that would be more efficient

Comment: @Androvich btw if you end up going with this please accept the answer :)

Comment: I have almost got it working! But I need to evaluate two seperate scripts on two different pages, since I need to login first.

How can I evaluate the JS content of a JS file on a certain page?

Comment: you can basically use `page.goto` to navigate to different pages, you can `await page.evaluate(() => location.href`)` to get the url of the current page loaded, this answers your question about two different pages i guess. About evaluating content of a JS file, the `evaluate` function accepts code as string as well, so you can do `await page.evaluate(fs.readFileSync('somefile.js'))`